# How to create a DataModule in Delphi 10.1

Tags: delphi-10.1-berlin, datamodule

I tried to create a DataModule for my non visible components in my multi-device-application, but the app won't compile giving me the following error:

[image]

Comment: That is not a compiler error, that is a DFM streaming error. Your DataModule's DFM contains a value for the `OldCreateOrder` property, but the streaming system is not able to find that property when loading the DFM into your `DataModule2` object. I don't have Berlin installed to check, but the `TDataModule.OldCreateOrder` property does exist in Seattle. But really, there should never be any reference to `OldCreateOrder` in a DFM since there is never a good reason to change the value of `OldCreateOrder` from its default value to begin with.

Comment: I just dropped the Datamodule by clicking File Menu > New > Other Files > Delphi > DataModule. Indeed there is an OldCreateOrder property. Can't remove it. Does this mean as of 10.1 you can't use a DataModule in a multi-device app?

Comment: No, it means this is clearly an IDE bug and should be reported to [Quality Portal](http://quality.embarcadero.com).

Answer (score 0):

Well, I hadn't been working on this app for very long so I started over and I was able to create and use the Datamodule just file. Not sure what the issue was, but thanks, guys. I actually thought I found a bug. Well, I did. It was me